# Login and Sign Up with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I created a login and sign up with passport.js for a website. Initially I used a list to store all my users. I want to use MongoDB to store the data of the users instead.

I think mongoose would be the right approach. But I am struggling to find the right way to access the data. I think I already found a way to store a user in MongoDB. Can someone help me to get rid of of the users list?

here is my server.js code:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  require('dotenv').config()
}

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const passport = require('passport')
const flash = require('express-flash')
const session = require('express-session')
const methodOverride = require('method-override')

const mongoose = require("mongoose")
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);


const User = require("./User")

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/userdb", () => {
  console.log("conncected")
},
e => console.error(e)
)




const initializePassport = require('./passport-config')
initializePassport(
  passport,
  email => user.find(user => user.email === email),
  id => users.find(user => user.id === id)
)


const users = []

app.set('view-engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(flash())
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))

app.get('/', checkAuthenticated,(req, res) => {
  res.render('index.ejs', { name: req.user.name })
})

app.get('/login', checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render('login.ejs')
})

app.get('/index', checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render('index.ejs')
})

app.post('/login', checkNotAuthenticated, passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  failureFlash: true
}))

app.get('/register', checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render('register.ejs')
})

app.post('/register', checkNotAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
    const user = await User.create({ id: Date.now().toString(), name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, password: hashedPassword })
    await user.save()
    console.log(user)
    users.push({
      id: Date.now().toString(),
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashedPassword
    })
    res.redirect('/login')
  } catch {
    res.redirect('/register')
  }
})


app.delete('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
  req.logout(function(err) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    res.redirect('/login');
  });
});

function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next()
  }

  res.redirect('/login')
}

function checkNotAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return res.redirect('/')
  }
  next()
}

app.listen(3000)
```

and my passport-config.js

```js
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) {
  const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
    const user = getUserByEmail(email)
    if (user == null) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Nutzer mit dieser Mail nicht vorhanden' })
    }

    try {
      if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        return done(null, user)
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Passwort falsch' })
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return done(e)
    }
  }

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, authenticateUser))
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id))
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    return done(null, getUserById(id))
  })
}

module.exports = initialize
```

and User.js for the schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const userSchema =  mongoose.Schema({
    id: String,
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("User",userSchema)
```